# Compare Image Size in KB in Java

Tags: java, filesize

I am using an api which gives me the size of an image, such as 200KB (can be MBs also). Now I need to perform some action on images below a specific size. What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
String imgSize = img.getSize();
if(imgSize < 250KB) {
  // Do Something
}
```

I can't use the relational operator here. What could be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer, you can also do something like this.  Convert the size to a size in bytes, then use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` to get an `int` value that you can check against.

```
String bytes = size.replace("KB", "000").replace("MB", "000000");

if (Integer.parseInt(bytes) <= 250000) {
    //Do something.
}
```

If you're dealing with fractional numbers, this can work.

```
Map<String, Integer> conversions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
conversions.put("KB", 1000);
conversions.put("MB", 1000000);

//Get numbers from String.
double doubleSize = Double.parseDouble(size.replaceAll("[A-Z]+$", "")); 
//Get units from String.
String units = size.replaceAll("[0-9.]", "");  

double bytes = doubleSize * conversions.get(units);

if (bytes <= 250000) {
    //Do something.
}
```

Comment: @Riaan, Will that scenario work in case I am getting image of size 90.52KB. Then it will be 90.52000. Thanks

Comment: @VivekDhiman - no, if you have fractional numbers you'll have to use another approach.

Comment: @VivekDhiman - sure.  This is similar to what the other answers have suggested though.

Answer (score 1):

Determine whether the `imgSize` is in KB or MB. Convert it to KB if in MB and use it.

```
String imgSize = "";
int imgSizeKB = 0;

switch (imgSize.toUpperCase()) {
    case "KB":
        imgSizeKB = (Integer.parseInt(imgSize.split("KB")[0]));
        break;
    case "MB":
        imgSizeKB = (Integer.parseInt(imgSize.split("MB")[0]) * 1024);
        break;
}

if(imgSizeKB < 250){
    // Do Something
}
```

Now you can use `if` statements as `imgSizeKB` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Check with:

```
imgSize.endsWith("KB");
```

Extract the number with a regex and multiply accordingly.